# To filter out the missing keys after comparing two json objects(used js filter but doesnt work for all the scenarios)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a functionality where I enable the user to edit the json object and then validate it in my code, so I have 2 json objects to compare and validate(the initial and the edited one) , I am pushing all the keys from json object into 2 different arrays and then comparing the first array to second and filtering out the missing keys.

The code works for rest of the scenarios(if I remove keys which has an object) but fails if the json has a key which has an array of objects and also starts filtering out the keys which has not been removed.

*Ex: conditionals, order when removed starts showing all the keys under conditionals as filtered out*

But if I remove keys under alert or offset it shows correct number and name of keys filtered out.

**note**:- for the stackblitz example I have written same function twice

```
let defaultJsonFormFields = [];
let editedJsonFormFields = []

function keyList1(obj){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        defaultJsonFormFields.push(key);
        if (typeof (obj[key]) == 'object') {
            keyList1(obj[key]);
        }
    });
};

function keyList2(obj){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        editedJsonFormFields.push(key);
        if (typeof (obj[key]) == 'object') {
            keyList2(obj[key]);
        }
    });
};


keyList1(defaultjson);
keyList2(editedjson);

console.log(defaultJsonFormFields);
console.log(editedJsonFormFields);

let result = defaultJsonFormFields.filter(item => editedJsonFormFields.indexOf(item) == -1)

console.log(result)
```

**[stackblitzlink]**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qkgdoa?file=index.js

```
let defaultjson =
 {
    "conditionals": [
        {
            "order": "1",
            "key": "gefvsgwer",
            "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",
            "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",
            "condition": ">"
        }
    ],
    "offset": "15",
    "alert": {
    "mAlertType": "so new thing",
    "mTitle": "abcdef",
    "mMessage": "ok so be it",
    "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
    "mSeverity": "LOW",
    "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}

let editedjson = {
    "": [
        {
            "": "1",
            "key": "gefvsgwer",
            "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",
            "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",
            "condition": ">"
         }
    ],
    "": "15",
    "": {
    "": "so new thing",
    "mTitle": "abcdef",
    "mMessage": "ok so be it",
    "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
    "mSeverity": "LOW",
    "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}
```

Stackblitz link with actual functionality

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-x1gtcp?file=app%2Fjson-input.component.ts

On hovering over the first column in table , a tooltip appears , on click of the button dialog box opens up which has edit json section, on click of Add As New Alert I want to check what all keys have been removed from the default json

Comment: at the end, you can have only the last value of same properties in an object. please add the data to the question as well.

Comment: Yeah sure will add the data

Comment: but it works not like that. please have a look to the data after initializing with data.

Comment: have a look with `console.log(editedjson)`. the array is gone.

Comment: Problem with your 2nd json, i.e. edited json, all the keys are "", so when JS object keys cant be duplicate. in that case it only considers the last "" :{} as only key of the object. You need to avoid that any how.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:**

After a little bit of thinking I realized that `RegExp`-s could work in your case without much of a fuss.

Keys in *JSON* are relatively easy to distinguish from string values:

```js
function test(str, regexp) {
  console.log(
    Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp), m => m[1])
  )
}
// to match a key
test(`{"key1": 1, "key2": 2}`, /\"(.*?)\":/g)
// to match a key followed by spases
test(`{"key1" \n: 1, "key2"\t: 2}`, /\"(.*?)\"\s*:/g)
// to ignore string values
test(`{"key1": "qwer", "key2": 2}`, /\"([^"]*?)\"\s*:/g)
// to ignore escapes in string values
test(`{"key1": "\\"not_a_key\\":", "key2": 2}`, /(?<!\\)\"([^"]*?)(?<!\\)\"\s*:/g)
```

So back to your code... You can see correct result in the following snippet:

```js
let defaultJsonFormFields = [
  "conditionals", "order", "key", "value", "grpOperation", "condition",
  "offset",
  "alert",
  "mAlertType", "mTitle", "mMessage", "mNotificationMsg", "mSeverity", "mEnabled",
]

const editedjson_str = '{\
  "": [{\
    "": "1",\
    "key": "gefvsgwer",\
    "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",\
    "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",\
    "condition": ">"\
  }],\
  "": "15",\
  "": {\
    "": "so new thing",\
    "mTitle": "abcdef",\
    "mMessage": "ok so be it",\
    "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",\
    "mSeverity": "LOW",\
    "mEnabled": "true"\
  }\
}'

let editedjson
// before checking the keys, try to  parse editedjson_str
// - no need to report key errors if JSON is invalid in general
//try {
    editedjson = JSON.parse(editedjson_str)
//} catch() { ... }

const editedJsonFormFields = Array.from(editedjson_str.matchAll(/(?<!\\)\"([^"]*?)(?<!\\)\"\s*:/g), m => m[1])
let result = defaultJsonFormFields.filter(item => editedJsonFormFields.indexOf(item) == -1)
console.log(result)
```

But still this approach feels like a dirty hack.

---

**Original answer:**

The only thing you need is to `log` your `editedjson` and you will see that it is not what you expect. Try it:

```js
let editedjson = {
    "": [{
            "": "1",
            "key": "gefvsgwer",
            "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",
            "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",
            "condition": ">"
        }],
    "": "15",
    "": {
        "": "so new thing",
        "mTitle": "abcdef",
        "mMessage": "ok so be it",
        "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
        "mSeverity": "LOW",
        "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}
console.log(editedjson)
```

The reason for this is that objects can't contain different value for the same key (and JSON as well). In this case you have in the root of `editedjson` 3 keys with the same value `""`, and only the last one stays. Others are overwritten.

If you'll clarify what is the exact behavior are you trying to achieve, I can update my answer with the code that will do.

The main issue is that you just can't get from a user an **object** with keys that are not unique. But you can get a **string** (and it probably shouldn't be called *JSON*)... but you really mustn't, because you'll have to parse it by yourself. So you need to choose another format for the data you expect from a user.

**Update:**

After update to your question I followed your [second link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-x1gtcp?file=app%2Fjson-input.component.ts) to the actual functionality and realized that I was to quick to suggest "the code that will do". As I see, you **do receive a string** from a user, and as I said **you really mustn't**. You will get nowhere with `JSON.parse()`. And I can not give you a full fledged parser for a **not even a JSON** with arbitrary errors in it. All I can suggest in this case is:

1. The best solution: use forms, with separate field for each value.
   As I see in the example, the data have a constant structure (also you compare it to the predefined `defaultjson`). If that's so - there is no reason to complicate things for a user and for yourself
2. Use regexp-s to check if any key from the `defaultJsonFormFields` are missing in the string. Or if there are duplicate keys. And only then try to `JSON.parse()`. But you will have hard times with a lot of edge cases. E.g. distinguishing

   ```
   { ... "key": "some text" ... }
   ```

   from

   ```
   { ... "wrong key": "key" ... }
   ```
3. For data of arbitrary structure, just change you approach for error reporting: if there is no `editedjson.conditionals` - report it, and don't try to report that `editedjson.conditionals.order` is also missing, but somehow everything is fine with `editedjson.conditionals.grpOperation` (because it's not - there is no such path as `editedjson.conditionals.grpOperation` as well)

Comment: I want to show missing keys between the default json object presented to the user and when the user starts editing the json object then the edited json object , so I want to filter out missing keys between  default json object and edited json object.

Comment: when keys such as offset, alert, mAlertType (rest of the keys under alert) are removed then on comparision between default json and edited json shows the renoved keys but if start removing the very first key 'conditionals' and 'order' particularly together then on comparision of the edited json with default json shows me the keys which have not been removed(essentially all the keys inside 'conditionals' array , I get that because the parent key doesnt exist so it filters out rest og the keys under it but is there any way thorugh which I can ony get the removed keys

Comment: stackblitz link with actual functionality https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-x1gtcp?file=app%2Fjson-input.component.ts ,on hovering over the first column in table , a tooltip appears , on click of the button dialog box opens up which had edit json section, on click of Add As New Alert I want to check what all keys have been removed from the default json

Comment: Sorry, I'm not into Angular, I'm more a React type of guy

Comment: Problem with this approach is you can't have this editedjson itself. You need to create this somehow.

Comment: @GouravGarg, what do you mean? `editedjson_str` created by a user and `editedjson` is a result of `parse(editedjson_str)`

Comment: Okay user has a form where he is seeing this json as a string he will just remove these keys and JSON.stringify will remove all those duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any way  to parse this JSON as it needs unique keys and will remove prior duplicate keys.

Basically JSON parser will see this edited json having single property

```
let editedjson = {
"": [
    {
        "": "1",
        "key": "gefvsgwer",
        "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",
        "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",
        "condition": ">"
     }
],
"": "15",
"": {
     "": "so new thing",
     "mTitle": "abcdef",
     "mMessage": "ok so be it",
     "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
     "mSeverity": "LOW",
     "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}
```

Output

```
let editedjson = {
"": {
      "": "so new thing",
      "mTitle": "abcdef",
      "mMessage": "ok so be it",
      "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
      "mSeverity": "LOW",
      "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}
```

And there is no way you can get back these removed properties.

However there is a way to keep loosing these keys in your existing application. I made some changes in that application

I added another function on "OnChange" event of the text area which will track this object change and will add 'key'+ i (where i will be incremental number) wherever user had removed from this json.

At that time this edited json will look like this:

```
let editedjson = {
"key1": [
    {
        "key0": "1",
        "key": "gefvsgwer",
        "value": "dghthdffbhrthrdvgrthtuem",
        "grpOperation": "wrfllkwjflmefveveveve",
        "condition": ">"
     }
],
"key2": "15",
"key4": {
     "key3": "so new thing",
     "mTitle": "abcdef",
     "mMessage": "ok so be it",
     "mNotificationMsg": "whatever",
     "mSeverity": "LOW",
     "mEnabled": "true"
    }
}
```

Then you can easily compare with your prev value and it should be exact.

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-dwmyb9?file=app/json-input.component.ts)

Comment: If instead of `""` a user enters two duplicate keys, one of them will be **deleted**, and not only invisible in the `editedjson`, but to the user as well. Also not all edits lead to "keyN"... it's a little bit chaotic, so can't say how, but more than once I managed to enter several `""` as keys. And copy-paste in the text field will fail with the same kind of issues as the original approach.

Comment: There are many ways to solve a problem. I am not saying this is perfect but can be improved. Yes there is a case where replace all kind of functionality can break this. All edits will lead to keyN without any doubt. Also these keys may be of no use. It's the programmer who has to decide will this solve his issue.

Comment: I had a look but not tried out, this looks a nicer way ,thinking out of the box and simple approach, will update, thanks :)