# To open angular material tooltip above when the page is scrolled and avoid the tooltip getting hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have added 2 tables in stackblitz link, if I hover in first table(1st column) alst rows the tooltip opens above(***expected***) but when we scroll down the page and then hover on the last rows of 2nd table, the tooltip gets hidden in the bottom of the screen, as was not the case if I have a single table.
I was expecting the tooltip to be opened above instead of getting hidden in the bottom. Please suggest.

***Stacblitz link***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-ctvigc?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html

**tooltip-overview-example.html**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Column1">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Alert </th>

     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" customToolTip [contentTemplate]="template">
          <span >{{row.Column1}}</span>
     <!--TOOLTIP-->
      <ng-template #template>
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
             <span>{{row.conditionals | json}}</span>
             <button (click)="onClick(i)">Click</button>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
      </td>

</ng-container>
```

Extended the Angular material TooltipComponent in CustomToolTipComponent

**custom-tool-tip.component.ts**

```
import {
 Component,
 OnInit,
 OnDestroy,
 Input,
 TemplateRef
 } from "@angular/core";
 import {TooltipComponent} from "@angular/material/tooltip"
 import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
 selector: "app-custom-tool-tip",
 templateUrl: "./custom-tool-tip.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./custom-tool-tip.component.css"]
})
export class CustomToolTipComponent extends TooltipComponent {

 @Input() text: string;
 @Input() contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

}
```

**custom-tool-tip.component.html**

```
<div>
 <div class="tooltip-conatiner">
  <ng-template #simpleText>
  {{text}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTemplate || simpleText">
  </ng-container>
</div>
</div>
```

**tool-tip-renderer.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[customToolTip]"
})
export class ToolTipRendererDirective {

@Input() showToolTip: boolean = true;

//If this is specified then specified text will be showin in the tooltip
 @Input(`customToolTip`) text: string;

//If this is specified then specified template will be rendered in the tooltip
 @Input() contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

private _overlayRef: OverlayRef;
private _tooltipInstance;
private _mouseInTooltip: boolean = false;
private _hasListeners: boolean = false;

constructor(
 private _overlay: Overlay,
 private _overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder,
 private _elementRef: ElementRef,
 private _r2: Renderer2
 ) {}


ngOnInit() {
 if (!this.showToolTip) {
  return;
}

const positionStrategy = this._overlayPositionBuilder
  .flexibleConnectedTo(this._elementRef)
  .withPositions([
    {
      originX: "center",
      originY: "bottom",
      overlayX: "center",
      overlayY: "top",
      offsetY: -10
    }
  ]);

this._overlayRef = this._overlay.create({ positionStrategy });
}


@HostListener("mouseenter")
show(e) {
if (this._overlayRef && !this._overlayRef.hasAttached()) {
  //set tooltip instance
  this._tooltipInstance = this._overlayRef.attach(
    new ComponentPortal(CustomToolTipComponent)
  ).instance;

  //set CustomToolTipComponenet content/inputs
  this._tooltipInstance.text = this.text;
  this._tooltipInstance.contentTemplate = this.contentTemplate;

  //render tooltip
  this._tooltipInstance!.show(0);

  //sub to detach after hide anitmation is complete
  this._tooltipInstance
    .afterHidden()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this._overlayRef.detach();
    });
  if (!this._hasListeners) {
    this._hasListeners = true;
    //attach mouseleave listener to detach when mouseleave on tooltip
    this._r2.listen(this._overlayRef.overlayElement, "mouseleave", () => {
      //call hide function in this directive
      this._mouseInTooltip = false;
      this.hide();
    });

    this._r2.listen(this._overlayRef.overlayElement, "mouseenter", () => {
      //call hide function in this directive
      this._mouseInTooltip = true;
    });
  }
}
}

@HostListener("mouseleave")
hide(buttonClicked = null) {
if(buttonClicked)
  this._mouseInTooltip = false;
setTimeout(() => {
  if (!this._mouseInTooltip) this._tooltipInstance!._onHide.next();
}, 20);
}
}
```

Comment: where is stackblitz link?

Comment: @GouravGarg, my bad missed it , have added now, thanks

Comment: Can you update your project to angular 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, you need to upgrade your cdk version to 7.3.7 which has a new method on OverlayRef as updatePositionStrategy.

According to this method you can change the position strategy of an overlay after attach.

In your show function after attaching the component you need to update position strategy as below:

```js
this._overlayRef.updatePositionStrategy(this._overlayPositionBuilder
  .flexibleConnectedTo(this._elementRef)
  .withPositions([{
    originX: "center",
    originY: "bottom",
    overlayX: "center",
    overlayY: "top",
    offsetY: this.getOffsetY()
  }]));
this._overlayRef.updatePosition();
```

where this.getOffsetY() is private method provide offset y value based on element current position. You may need to update this logic.

```js
private getOffsetY() {
  if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 500)
    return -400;
  if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 400)
    return -300;
  if (this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 300)
    return -200;
  return -10;
}
```

Here is stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-hpzy4q?file=app%2Ftool-tip-renderer.directive.ts)

Comment: thanks, This works beautifully , but  when I am hovering at the bottom 2 last rows then the tooltip opens above the 1st row not on the row where the mosue is hovered , as in the top rows it opens just below or above the hovered row , so I changed the return values of getOffsetY() function to smaller number like instead of -400 , chnaged to -100 , -80 , would that be correct approach

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that, you need to change as per your actual look and feel

Comment: One thing but if there are more numbers of rows in the table and I scroll down then the scroll value is not taken into account and again tootip starts getting hidden in the bottom,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-h2jxgc?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.ts

Comment: You need to create a formula around this. Like for 500 you can do something like (500/-10)-50 which will return -100 or something respective to space between element and body

Comment: yeah but I think I should be taking into account how much the page is scrolled incase if the oage is scrolled I should add that , how should I be registering this in this directive and modifyin the y , because my main issue is that , hiding of the tooltip when the page is scrolled and bottom rows are hovered upon

Comment: you can try by this private getOffsetY(){
   if((document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom -this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom)<450){
     return -450+document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom -this._elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
   }
    return -10;
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211710/discussion-between-enthu-and-gourav-garg).

Comment: Actually that gives me a solution :) but its not working as expected , trying to figure out in all scenarios it should work

Answer (score -1):

You can get the event.screenX and Event   event.screenY  position and using that check the height of the screen by getting screen height and screen width .

`screen.height`

Then check if the event is not near to the screen height if then make the  `[matTooltipPosition]="position.value"` to be above..

Like this you have to check

Comment: [matTooltipPosition]={{position}}. Pass the value in here

Comment: Can you please elaborate just passing the position in which file should I pass it, not able to understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883450/to-filter-out-the-missing-keys-after-comparing-two-json-objectsused-js-filter-b/61077875 resolved?